# "message":"Head \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/testcontainers/ryuk/manifests/0.3.0\": unauthorized: incorrect username or password" when run test

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, junit5, testcontainers

I have added testcontainer in spring boot app

```java
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ProductServiceApplicationTests {

    @Container
    static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.4.2");

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri",mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldCreateProduct() throws Exception {

        ProductRequest productRequest = getProductRequest();
        String productRequestString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productRequest);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/product")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(productRequestString)
        ).andExpect(status().isCreated()) ;
    }

    private ProductRequest getProductRequest() {
        return ProductRequest.builder()
                .name("Iphone 13")
                .description("Iphone 13")
                .price(BigDecimal.valueOf(1200))
                .build();
    }


}
```

- I have installed docker desktop and logged it using docker desktop And then try using cli.

When Running it
Getting the below error

com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/testcontainers/ryuk/manifests/0.3.0": unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}
at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247)
at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[image: Error message in the terminal]

Comment: You need to provide more information about the problem or your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I think you need to create a DockerHub account and ensure you're logged in.

Comment: I have created dockerHub account and also logged in using cli and also using docker desktop.

Comment: I have the same problem happening with me now. Latest spring boot version, latest testcontainers (1.17.1), latest Docker desktop (Windows - 4.8.1).
That being said, it works fine in Azure pipeline, which is based off of Linux OS. But I can't run tests locally anymore except if I download Ryuk docker image manually `docker pull testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3`

I can see my credentials are loaded:
`DEBUG o.t.utility.RegistryAuthLocator - Cached auth found: [AuthConfig{username=XXXXXXX, password=hidden non-blank value, auth=blank, email=null, registryAddress=index.docker.io, registryToken=blank}]`

Comment: @Gopal It's good that you found a solution, but please don't post it as an update to your question. Instead, post your solution in an answer, and also accept that answer. That approach is strongly encouraged here, because it is much more helpful for the community to have questions with accepted answers. I'll be happy to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This helped me:

```
$ docker logout
$ docker login --username your_username_here
```

Found it here - https://forums.docker.com/t/unauthorized-incorrect-username-or-password/35677/4

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the command `netcfg -d` in Command Prompt then restart your PC.
   This worked for me

Reference
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3422

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me on an M1 Mac was:

1. remove `credsStore:desktop` from ~/.docker/config.json
2. run `docker login` in terminal